# Hadoop CDH3 ERROR. Could not start Hadoop datanode daemon

Tags: hadoop, startup, bigdata, cloudera

I'm deploying Hadoop CDH3 in pseudo-distributed mode on a VPS.

So i have installed CDH3, then i have executed

`sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo`

but if i try to start all daemons with

`for service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-*; do sudo $service start; done`

it throws

`ERROR. Could not start Hadoop datanode daemon`

The same installation and starting commands works on my notebook.

I don't understand the cause. In fact the log file is empty. The available RAM is about 900MB, with 98G of available disk space. 
Which can be the cause or how can i discover it? I'm excluding that the error is from the configuration files.

Comment: It's had to say unless we can take a look at the logs. Do you see anything in the appropriate *.log file under /var/log?

Comment: @MarkGrover as I asid all log files are empty in folder /var/log/hadoop-0.20/

Comment: I'm trying with installation from tarball. If i execute start-all.sh it throws `May not run daemons as root. Please specify HADOOP_NAMENODE_USER`.
Executing `sudo -u hdfs bin/start-all.sh` throws `bin/start-all.sh: line 24: /root/opt/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u5/bin/hadoop-config.sh: Permission denied`.

Comment: It seems that the last problem (specified in previuos comment) is resolved (exporting HADOOP_>DATANODE/NAMENODE/ETC.>_USER) beacuse no error message is throwed. But executing start-all.sh, even if no error is displayed, services aren't started.

Comment: Are these files executable? (ls -l /root/opt/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u5/bin/hadoop-config.sh)

Comment: Use below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725804/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-mode-datanode-and-tasktracker-not-starting

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Cloudera Manager](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera+Manager+Downloads), it could save you some time (especially if you use multiple nodes). There is a nice [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CobVqNMiqww)  on Youtube which shows deployment process