# Hadoop pseudo distributed mode - Datanode and tasktracker not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, redhat

I am running a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago) distribution with Hadoop 1.1.2 installed on it. I have made the required configurations to enable the pseudo distributed mode. But on trying to run hadoop, the datanode and tasktracker don't start.

I am not able to copy any files to hdfs.

```
[hduser@is-joshbloom-hadoop hadoop]$ hadoop dfs -put README.txt /input
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

13/05/23 16:42:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /input could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
```

Also after trying `hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode` I get the message:

```
starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-is-joshbloom-hadoop.out
```

same goes for tasktracker. But when I try the same command for namenode, secondarynamenode, jobtracker they are seem to be running.

```
namenode running as process 32933. Stop it first.
```

I tried the following solutions:

1. Reformatting namenode
2. Reinstalling hadoop
3. Installing different version of hadoop (1.0.4)

None seem to work. I have followed the same installation steps on my Mac and on amazon ubuntu VM and it works perfectly.

How can I get hadoop working?
Thanks!

*UPDATE**

Here is the log entry of namenode

```
2013-05-23 16:27:44,087 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = java.net.UnknownHostException: is-joshbloom-hadoop: is-joshbloom-hadoop
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.1.2
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.1 -r 1440782; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Thu Jan 31 02:03:24 UTC 2013
************************************************************/
2013-05-23 16:27:44,382 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-05-23 16:27:44,432 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-05-23 16:27:44,446 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Error getting localhost name. Using 'localhost'...
java.net.UnknownHostException: is-joshbloom-hadoop: is-joshbloom-hadoop
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
        at     org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.getHostname(MetricsSystemImpl.java:463)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configureSystem(MetricsSystemImpl.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configure(MetricsSystemImpl.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.start(MetricsSystemImpl.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.init(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:40)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.initialize(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1608)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1751)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: is-joshbloom-hadoop
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
        ... 11 more
2013-05-23 16:27:44,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled     snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-05-23 16:27:44,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode     metrics system started
2013-05-23 16:27:44,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-05-23 16:27:44,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2013-05-23 16:27:45,212 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode:     java.net.UnknownHostException: is-joshbloom-hadoop: is-joshbloom-hadoop
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getLocalHostName(SecurityUtil.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1608)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1751)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: is-joshbloom-hadoop
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
        ... 8 more

2013-05-23 16:27:45,228 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: is-joshbloom-hadoop: is-joshbloom-hadoop
************************************************************/
```

*UPDATE***

content of `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: @ChrisWhite - this is how `hosts` looks like

Comment: `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4



     ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amend your `/etc/hosts` to include a hostname loopback mapping:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.1.1   is-joshbloom-hadoop
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Your problem is your machine doesn't know how to resolve the hostname `is-joshbloom-hadoop` to a specific IP address. There are typically two places/methods resolution occurs - either via a DNS server or using a local hosts file (hosts file takes precedence).

The above amendment to your hosts file allows you machine to resolve the machine name `is-joshbloom-hadoop` to the IP address `127.0.1.1`. The OS has an internal loopback address for the range `127.0.0.0/8`, so you could name any address in here. On my Ubuntu laptop, it uses the `127.0.1.1` and i'm sure it changes between OS's, but my guess is by not using `127.0.0.1` you don't have to search for it in the localhost line if you change your machine name in future.

Comment: Can you please explain me what hostname loopback mapping is? And also why `127.0.1.1` instead of `127.0.0.1` ?
I appreciate your efforts. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just tried it out and its all working?
Can you explain me what we just did?

Answer (score 2):

Check your core-site.xml in HADOOP_HOME/conf.It will have **fs.default.name** property.It should have a hostname specified in your /etc/hosts."is-joshbloom-hadoop" hostname is not there in /etc/hosts.Use localhost instead

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have the core-site.xml which looks exactly like this. But I don't have the "is-joshbloom-hadoop" in the hosts file. Should I can my core-site.xml to `<value>hdfs://is-joshbloom-hadoop:54310</valuse>` or just leave it the same?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be like that u have nothing in slaves file under conf/slaves.

Check your slaves file in conf/slaves.Remove everything and add localhost in that file.Remove the name and data directory mentioned in dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir property under hdfs-site.xml.

Format ur HDFS file system and then start ur daemons again.